# Correctly setting up MMDevice in a DirectX project

Tags: c++, windows, directx, wasapi

I am currently trying to piece together a shader-based music visualizer. The plan is to read data from the current `MMDevice`, which I'm trying to follow the documentation for, but I must be doing something wrong because I had to jump through all sorts of hoops to get even just the `MMDeviceEnumerator` to compile.

In order for the `uuid`s of `MMDeviceEnumerator` and `IMMDeviceEnumerator` to be defined, I had to set `#define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_GAMES`. This was also required for `EDataFlow` and `ERole` enumerations to be defined. **My first question is if I've missed some configuration somewhere, or if this is the intended method of enabling these things**.

Currently, I have the following code in an `AudioStream` class:

```cpp
class AudioStream {
public:
    AudioStream() {
        //SUCCEEDING(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));
        SUCCEEDING(CoCreateInstance(
            __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_ALL, 
            __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),
            (void**)&this->mmDeviceEnumerator));
        SUCCEEDING(this->mmDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
            eRender,
            eConsole,
            &this->mmDevice));
    }

private: 
    IAudioClient* audioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient* captureClient = NULL;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* mmDeviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* mmDevice = NULL;
};
```

If you're familiar with what the DirectX 12 project template looks like, this object is being instantiated in the `Sample3DSceneRenderer` constructor. **The main issue I'm having right now is the following two errors which are immediately raised during startup**:

```
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\resolver.cxx(2299)\combase.dll!75AA0DFF: (caller: 75B1CF2C) ReturnHr(1) tid(42a8) 80040154 Class not registered
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\resolver.cxx(2507)\combase.dll!75B1CF4D: (caller: 75AA29E4) ReturnHr(2) tid(42a8) 80040154 Class not registered
```

This causes the entire app to hang, and the project template visualization to never appear (the succeeding macro exits). Does anyone have any idea why this is failing? It must have to be something with the `CoCreateInstance` call :(

Comment: Are you writing a Win32 desktop application or are you writing a UWP app?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the distinction. I think it's a Win32 desktop application. Where could I check/what's the implication :0

Comment: Well, look for your Main.cpp file. If it has ``[Platform::MTAThread] int __cdecl main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ /*argv*/)`` or ``auto viewProviderFactory = winrt::make<ViewProviderFactory>();  CoreApplication::Run(viewProviderFactory);`` then it's a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/) and will be subject to more stringent  device access than a classic Win32 desktop app.

Comment: My guess is that you are writing a UWP and you hacked the API access by defining ``WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_GAMES`` which is NOT SUPPORTED for UWP apps.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a ton of sense. Is it possible to easily transition to a win32 app from the existing DirectX code? Is there a project template or anything like that I could refer to?

Comment: https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app because that's what the "built-in" *DirectX 12 App* project template creates in Visual Studio. UWPs do not have access to all the same APIs and IMMDevice is *not* part of the UWP API surface area.

The fact that you defined `WINAPI_FAMILY_GAMES` means you hacked the API Family Partition macros which will *define* the API in a UWP context, but it doesn't mean that API actually *works* from the AppContainer process that all UWPs run in.

You really have two options:

(1) If you *want* to write a UWP, then you will need to enumerate audio devices via the proper Windows Runtime APIs which are in the `Windows::Devices::Enumeration` namespace.

Assuming you are using [C++/CX language extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx) (instead of the more modern [C++/WinRT projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/)), then this code works:

```
auto operation = DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(DeviceClass::AudioRender);
while (operation->Status == Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus::Started)
{
    Sleep(100);
}
if (operation->Status != Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus::Completed)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("FindAllAsync");
}

DeviceInformationCollection^ devices = operation->GetResults();

for (unsigned i = 0; i < devices->Size; ++i)
{
    using Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation;

    DeviceInformation^ d = devices->GetAt(i);

    // d->Id->Data();
    // d->Name->Data();
}
```

> Also, if you want to get access to the audio capture device from a UWP, you must add a *capability* to your manifest to request it via `<DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-in-a-package-manifest).

You should take the time to read the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/) on UWPs so you have a better idea of what's supported and what's not.

(2) If you *want* to write a Win32 desktop app, use the [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) instead which include DirectX 12 starting templates for Win32 desktop apps (plus alternative DirectX templates for UWP if that's your thing).

> Whichever appmodel you use, you may want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio).

> BTW, `WINAPI_FAMILY_GAMES` is used by the *Microsoft GDK for Xbox* which is for writing titles for Xbox One and Xbox Series X|S. It uses Win32 APIs and doesn't use Windows Runtime APIs, so it has the `IMMDevice` interface in it's API surface. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/gdkintroduction).

Comment: Thank you, this is absolutely wonderful. Hopefully this post will make it easier for people to find it.